# How can we calculate or estimate the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n-a}}$ from above?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I thought that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n-a}}$ could be represented as something involving $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}}$, for which the value is known, but I didn't manage to represent it in a form that I would be able to calculate. Is there a way to estimate it from above or calculate it precisely without using difficult methods?

It's important to mention that $a \in \mathbb R$ and $0 < a < 1$.

EDIT.
Difficult methods include computing special functions such as, for example, the Lerch transcendent function or the Clausen function, mentioned in answers.

Comment: In terms of the generalised [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#General_definition), it is $\frac{1}{a}\sum_{k = 1}^\infty a^k {\rm S}_k (x)$.

Comment: @Gary, I've clarified what I mean by difficult methods. I need quite a simple estimate without the need to compute functions of special type.

Comment: Please, do not change the question after having received an answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I only specified what I mean by "difficult methods". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n-a}}=\Im\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{inx}}{n-a}}\right)=\Im\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{[e^{ix}]^n}{n-a}}\right)=\Im\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{t^n}{n-a}}\right)$$ with $t=e^{ix}$

There is a special function
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{t^n}{n-a}}=t\, \Phi (t,1,1-a)$$ where appears  the [Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html) and if $a=0$ it gives $-\log(1-t)$.

So,
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n-a}}=\Im\Big[e^{i x} \Phi \left(e^{i x},1,1-a\right)\Big]}$$

Let us try it for $x=\frac \pi {12}$ to see the impact of $a$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin \left(n\frac{\pi  }{12}\right)}{n-a}}\\
 0.0 & 1.43990 \\
 0.1 & 1.50531 \\
 0.2 & 1.58060 \\
 0.3 & 1.66924 \\
 0.4 & 1.77679 \\
 0.5 & 1.91305 \\
 0.6 & 2.09718 \\
 0.7 & 2.37321 \\
 0.8 & 2.87165 \\
 0.9 & 4.24105
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If you cannot use the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function, you can use the expansion
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{t^n}{n-a}}=-\log(1-t)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \text{Li}_{k+1}(t)\,a^k$$

Comment: In my terms, it's difficult to calculate. Can we find the estimate from above without computing functions of special type?

Comment: the same problem still holds. Polylogarithm computation is not trivial at all.