# How can we estimate $\left |\sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil+1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2-a^2}} \right |$ from above?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can we estimate $\left |\sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil+1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2-a^2}} \right |$ from above? $a$ is real and positive.

It's not allowed to neglect the sine, i.e. such simplification as $\left |\sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil+1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2-a^2}} \right | \leq \sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil+1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2-a^2}}$ and further estimation using the integral is not allowed.

It's also not allowed to compute $\sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil+1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2-a^2}}$ precisely using functions of special type such as dilogarithm, Lerch transcendent function, etc. It's expected that the estimation doesn't use very specific knowledge (e.g. computation of the functions mentioned above).

Comment: Maybe factorize denominator into $(n-a)(n+a)$... . But not sure if that helps

Comment: @Meowdog, it leads us to computation of $\frac{1}{2a}\left |\sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil+1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n-a}}-\sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil+1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n+a}} \right |$ And I don't understand what to do next. I tried to ask the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450300/how-can-we-calculate-or-estimate-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sinnx?noredirect=1#comment9320958_4450300. But, first, it's not answered the way it's supposed to, and, second, I think it won't really help anyway.

Comment: What do you mean it's "not allowed"? Who's making the rules?

Comment: @K.defaoite, that's me. I wouldn't like the solution to be too "bad" or use functions I cannot calculate by myself.

Comment: Basic methods only work on basic problems.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with $\;\displaystyle f_a(x):=\sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil+1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{n^2-a^2}}\;$  then :
$$\tag{1}f_a(x)=\frac{x^{\lceil a\rceil+1}}{2\,a}\left(\Phi(x,1,\lceil a\rceil-a+1)-\Phi(x,1,\lceil a\rceil+a+1)\right)$$
with $\;\displaystyle\Phi(x, s, \alpha) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac { x^n} {(n+\alpha)^s}\;$ the [Lerch transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Definition).

This may be proved by observing that :

\begin{align}
f_a(x)&=\sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil+1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{n^2-a^2}}\\
&=\frac 1{2a}\left(\sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil+1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n-a}-\sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil+1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n+a}\right)\\
\tag{2}&=\frac 1{2a}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+\lceil a\rceil+1}}{n+\lceil a\rceil+1-a}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+\lceil a\rceil+1}}{n+\lceil a\rceil+1+a}\right)\\
\\
&\text{we may too write this as integrals :}\\
\\
f_a(x)&=\frac{x^a}{2a}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^x z^{n+\lceil a\rceil-a}\; dz-\frac{x^{-a}}{2a}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^x z^{n+\lceil a\rceil+a}\; dz\\
\tag{3}&=\frac{x^a}{2a}\int_0^x \frac {z^{\lceil a\rceil-a}}{1-z}\; dz-\frac{x^{-a}}{2a}\int_0^x \frac{z^{\lceil a\rceil+a}}{1-z}\; dz\\
\tag{4}&=\frac{x^{\lceil a\rceil+1}}{2a}\int_0^1 \frac{t^{\lceil a\rceil}\left(t^{-a}-t^a\right)}{1-x\,t}\; dt\\
\end{align}

The series of interest will be given by the imaginary part of $\; \displaystyle f_a(e^{ix})$.

Excellent approximations are obtained using [Euler-Maclaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) as shown for example by [Guillermo Navas-Palencia](https://gnpalencia.org/research/GNP_Lerch_2018.pdf) (using $\Gamma(0,a)=-\operatorname{Ei}(-a)\;$ i.e. the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definitions)) :
$$\Phi(x, 1, \alpha) \sim  \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}
\frac { x^k} {k+\alpha}-\frac{\operatorname{Ei\left((N+\alpha)\log x\right)}}{x^\alpha}+\frac { x^N} {N+\alpha}\left(\frac 12+\frac{B_2}{2!}\frac { (N+\alpha)\log(x)-1}{N+\alpha}+\cdots\right)$$
(this is an asymptotic expansion so that including or not the $B_2=\frac 16$ Bernoulli term should provide two bounds for the exact value!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Lerch transcendent is not allowed to use (it's written in the question).

Comment: I fear having missed that part (sorry). Anyway the last line could be useful (with $x$ replaced by $\,\displaystyle e^{ix}\,$ and the comparison with the series for the logarithm...)

Comment: I have no idea how to compare them...

Comment: You may rewrite the result as integrals as shown (and possibly find something simple from your point of view...). I used Euler-Maclaurin to obtain accurate bounds (larger $N$ will provide better precision). Excellent continuation,